# Using Apache Bench to load test with JSON on Windows

Tags: apache, apachebench

I'm issuing the following command:

```
 ab -n 100 -c 20 -k -v 1 -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -T "application/json" -p ab-login.txt http://localhost:222/
```

With the contents of `ab-login.txt` being:

```
 {username:'user',password:'pass!'}
```

And I get an error:

```
Could not stat POST data file (ab-login.txt): Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I've found your question after googling about ab+json. I think that your problem was with invalid json format: `{"username": "user", "password": "pass!"}`

Answer (score 0):

I added
 -v 4 -T 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Also, a line in my post file looked like:
name='myName'

There were no quotes or anything like that.